# ¿Qué quiere decir "para calarse"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Contexto:

> Mi Popo nada sabía de ese deporte, porque no es popular en Estados Unidos, pero no vaciló en abandonar el béisbol, del cual era fanático,
>   **para calarse** cientos de partidos infantiles femeninos de fútbol.

¿Qué quiere decir "para calarse"? Si quiere decir "sumergirse en", ¿por qué falta "en" como en cada otro ejemplo he encontrado?

Claro que no puede significar [parar un coche aquí](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6i93wwC).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seguramente esté haciendo un símil con «calarse el sombrero»:

> **[calar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6i74jwO%7C6i85AxB)**
>      5. tr. Ponerse una gorra, un sombrero, etc., haciéndolos entrar mucho en la cabeza. U. t. c. prnl.

En este sentido, se crea la figura del padre metiendo la cabeza todo lo que puede en ese, para él, extraño mundo del fútbol infantil femenino.

Comment: De acuerdo. También se ajusta la definición 11.  tr. coloq. **Entrarse, introducirse en alguna parte**

Answer (score 2):

Voy a proponer otra idea:

> **Calar**: 11. Entrarse, introducirse en alguna parte. ([DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6i74jwO%7C6i85AxB))

O sea que el papá entró de lleno en el mundo de futbol.

Y una idea más:

> 18. (Dicho de una persona) Mojarse hasta que el agua u otro líquido, penetrando la ropa, llegue al cuerpo. ([DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6i74jwO%7C6i85AxB))

Es decir, el papá se empapó de partidos de futbol.

También preguntaste por qué faltaba *en*.  No sé explicar esto pero encontré en [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/spanish-english/translation/calarse.html) una gran variedad de preposiciones usadas con *calarse*.