# Translation-golf XIX - Moominland Midwinter

Tags: traducción, translation-golf, sueco

Welcome to yet another edition of Translation Golf!
If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

---

## And the winner is...

@VeAqui with 168 letters. Regardless of me having absolute authority, I feel obliged to defend this decision: the last sentence of the translation has caused some raised eyebrows in the chat. Even if this sentence was judged as unacceptable and replaced with the ungolfed "Mamá la llamó nieve, susurró." (longer than any bronze-bringing solutions), the translation would be of length 172, one character below the tied silver score of 173 letters. Congratulations.

Mumble @walen mumble grumble.

---

[image: Moominland Midwinter - Trollvinter cover]

Being one of the fierce Vikings of the north and with fall turning to winter, I would like to propose something showcasing Finnish litterature. The text is an excerpt from the official English translation of *Moominland Midwinter* or *Trollvinter* in the original Swedish (Finland is a bilingual country: we speak both Finnish and Swedish). The protagonist of this children's book, Moomintroll has just unexpectedly awoken from his hibernation and is taking a peek outside the house. He is the first Moomin to ever be awoken during the winter.

> He lost his breath, slipped and rolled over the edge.
>   And so Moomintroll was helplessly thrown out in a strange and dangerous world and dropped up to his ears in the first snowdrift of his experience. It felt unpleasantly prickly to his velvet skin, but at the same time his snout caught a new smell. It was a more serious smell than any he had felt before, and slightly frightening. But it made him wide awake and greatly interested.
>
> The valley was enveloped in a kind of grey twilight. It also wasn’t green any longer, it was white. Everything that had once moved had become immobile. There were no living sounds. Everything angular was now rounded.
>   ‘This is snow,’ Moomintroll whispered to himself. ‘I’ve heard about it from Mother, and it’s called snow.’
>
> <sub>(601 caracteres)</sub>

Here is my attempt at a translation (I encourage you all to point out any errors you can find so that I can fix them. If the meaning is somewhat different it is because I tried to match the Swedish text. The source material to golf against is the English translation, though.):

> Él perdió su aliento*, se resbaló y rodó sobre el el borde del techo. Asi se encontró Mumin indefenso en un mundo nuevo y peligroso y hundo profundamente en el primero lomo de nieve de su vida. Picó su piel velludo desagradablemente, pero mientras tanto captó su morro un olor nuevo. Era un olor más serioso que ningún que hubiera sentido antes y también un poco alarmante. Por otro lado le hizo vigilante y interesado.
>
>  Una penumbra grise envolvía el valle y no era el mismo valle verde sino blanco. Todo lo que se había movido estaba ahora inmóvil. Todos los ruidos de la vida faltaban. Todo lo que había sido rudo era ahora redondeado. 'Es nieve', murmuró Mumin a si mismo, 'Mamá ha oido hablar des esa y se llama nieve.'
>
>
>  <sub>(573 caracteres)</sub>

And would someone want to see the original Swedish text, here it is:

> Han tappade andan, halkade och rullade över takkanten. Och så åkte Mumintrollet hjälplöst ut i en ny farlig värld och sjönk djupt ner i sin första snödriva. Det stack obehagligt i hans sammetsskinn, men samtidigt vädrade hans nos en ny lukt. Den var allvarligare än någon lukt han känt och lite skrämmande. Men den gjorde honom klarvaken och intresserad.
>
> En grå halvdager låg tät över dalen. Men dalen var inte grön längre, den var vit. Allt som rörde sig hade blivit orörligt. Alla levande ljud var borta. Allt kantigt hade blivit runt.
>   Det är snö, viskade Mumintrollet. Mamma har hört talas om den och den kallas snö.
>
> <sub>(497 caracteres)</sub>

---

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's (that is the **English translation**) meaning and concepts more or less intact.

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contesters?
Join us in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

## Clarification

The English expression `he lost his breath` is ambiguous. The following interpretations are accepted:

- Moomintroll was taken impressed by the snowy landscape and couldn't find words to describe it. (Quedó sin habla)
- Moomintroll was tired and hyperventilating: he lost his balance because of this. (Estaba cansado)
- Moomintroll had a physical reaction to the cold and/or was surprised by what he saw and/or the sensation of cold: he physically emptied his lungs.

Comment: @walen Si, se ha hecho por japoneses.

Comment: @walen ¿Pueden ser estos dibujos de los que hablas? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjbiyAdu_qc.  Salen esos bichos como el de la portada del libro.

Comment: @blonfu Si. ¿Son conocidos en países hispanohablantes?

Comment: [O al menos son los de que hablo yo]

Comment: Yo los recuerdo vagamente. No creo que sean demasiado conocidos al menos en España

Comment: Los dibujos animados se han adaptado de los libros y son para niños pequeños. Los libros de pueden leer por adultos también debida a sus cualidades literales. La escritora Tove Jansson también ha ilustrado los libros: estaba también una pintora.

Comment: @walen Si, me equivoco con el nombre del presonaje. Disculpen.

Comment: @walen hacía mucho que no veía un Rickroll.

Comment: Y creía que fue el niño yo... Los dos expertos del idioma Español rickrolleandose...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**<strike>262</strike> <strike>239</strike> <strike>207</strike> <strike>174</strike> 168 Caracteres**

> Muerto, Mumin rodó y cayó solo a un difícil mundo, a flor de nieve. Sintió picar su piel velluda y un olor nuevo y grave lo excitó. Tras un ocaso gris el valle albo, quedo, mudo, curvo, sin verde "Oí a Mamá, ¿Nieve?" susurró

Esto se ha puesto bueno... ¿serán menos de 160 caracteres del ganador?

- [Muerto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Q0NUNXM) viene en su cuarta acepción (muy fatigado)
- Si está solo no tiene ayuda
- [Difícil](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DjoVnu9) en su tercer significado es extraño (raro) y en su primero, al presentar obstáculos puede verse como peligroso
- Similar a las expresiones "A flor de agua" o "A flor de tierra" podría usarse un "A flor de nieve" para dar a entender que está cubierto parcialmente por la nieve
- [Picar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SsuIXMH) en su significado 29 es: Dicho de una parte del cuerpo de alguien: Hacerle experimentar picor.
- El olor debe ser sentido por su nariz (u hocico)
- [Grave](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JVSZmEi) entraría con sus significados 4 y 7 (Circunspecto, serio, que causa respeto y veneración. Molesto, enfadoso)
- Si el olor lo [excitó](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HCPDpRu), debió quedar despierto
- El valle envuelto quedaría detrás del ocaso o mejor *tras un* ocaso
- Trato de resumir en pocas palabras las descripciones de la nieve.
- Las frases de la madre de Mumin la pongo como una sola.
- Planteo la pregunta en término retórico, por un par de letras...

Cualquier duda a corregir me comentan, ya que por lo visto el chat lo realizan a eso de la 13:00 UTC.

Comment: ¿Es posible ”decirlo algo” para ”llamarlo algo”? ¿O quiere decir “decir que es algo”? Nunca lo he encontrado antes. Voy a acceptarlo si un otro jugador dice que válido o encontro un ejemplo en una otra fuente. No tienes que cambiarlo ya.

Comment: ¿Se trata de eso: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/llamar-decir.1371619/ ?

Comment: gracias por la ayuda @walen, pues esto se está poniendo a mermar bastante. El tercer significado de [decir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BxLriBU|BxMOE45) es nombrar o llamar

Comment: Lo difícil no es difícil a aceptar, pero el muerto no va a sobrevivir a mi. No es lo que el inglés intenta decir: Mumin no puede respirar por sorpresa y frío, no por estar cansado. Lo demás es muy buen trabajo, no había pensado que haría una respuesta con menos de tres cientos caracteres postando el texto. Perdón por los mensajes Chat a horas inhumanas.

Comment: El exánime de @walen se refiere al sentido dos, 'Sumamente debilitado, sin aliento, desmayado.'

Comment: Una reducción espectacular, te has puesto en cabeza con una propuesta muy buena. Solo un apunte: "a flor de agua" o "de tierra" significa lo mismo que "a ras de": "en la superficie, sobre o cerca de la superficie" según el DLE. Por tanto, "a flor de nieve" da a entender "en la superficie de la nieve", pero no que esté hundido (aunque sea parcialmente).

Comment: He decidado que porque el texto ingles, la fuente de la traducción, no es claro, voy a acceptar tres sentidos para 'He lost his breath':

1. Quedó sin palabra 2. Se cansó 3. El aire frío impedío su respiración

Comment: Bueno, gracias a @Mörkö por aceptarme el muerto. En cuanto el "a flor de agua" me basé en un cuento de Horacio Quroga [aquí](http://ciudadseva.com/texto/la-guerra-de-los-yacares/) en donde dice que _el torpedo vino a flor de agua_ y un torpedo queda sumergido cuando es lanzado, no sé sea válido

Comment: Lo excepcional de que el torpedo vaya _a flor de agua_ es precisamente que no vaya sumergido, que sería lo normal. Es decir, está acercándose a una superficie desde su entorno habitual (bajo el agua). Aquí la situación excepcional es que Mumin está sumergido en la nieve cuando no debería. Por eso, si dices que Mumin está _a flor de nieve_ lo que entiendo es lo mismo que si dijeras _a flor de suelo_: que está sobre el suelo o la nieve, pero no enterrado en ella, ya que se acerca a su superficie desde su entorno habitual (sobre la nieve).

Comment: Pienso que la última frase no es clara; tendrás que cambiarla.

Comment: Como ganador del muy prestigioso Translation Golf, tienes 48 horas para elegir el tema de la partida siguiente.

Comment: Con dos respuestas con 173 letras nombra a @CarlosAlejo cómo segundo; su traducción me gusta estilísticamente un poco más que la de blonfu.

Comment: Larga Vida y Prosperidad.

Comment: Y si quieres, puedes dar el derecho de elección al segundo clasificado. Si no haces nada, después de 48 horas quienquiera puede proponer el siguiente.

Answer (score 4):

> **Fuera de concurso**
>   Como ganador de la edición anterior, considero que mi respuesta no debe tenerse en cuenta para esta edición.

#### <strike>248 181</strike> 129

> Sin voz va Mumin filo abajo, de morro a lo nuevo: níveo capuzón, pelaje agujado, asombroso olor.
>   So luz gris, el ex verde valle albo, quedo, sin canto.
>   — Nieve, según mamá.

Tras la aclaración de @Mörkö, cambio "exánime" por "sin voz".
El guión largo o [raya](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=VEnqyiQ#I2ix0tI) es el símbolo usado para indicar texto hablado.
Puesto que Mumin está sin voz, su habla no puede ser sino un susurro, a lo sumo.

Varias de las acepciones de "nuevo" apuntan a algo que se experimenta por primera vez, que no se conocía antes: desconocido.

Creo que es importante no eliminar "morro" ni "pelaje" porque, de hacerlo, no estaría claro que Mumin no es una persona. Así que muevo "morro" a la forma de caer, y ya se sobreentiende que el olor lo capta con el morro.

Lo demás que no esté en el histórico, lo explico en comentarios, a petición.

Comment: Tengo sólo una queja: aqui tambien falta el sentido de que mamá no estaba segura hablando de nieve.

Comment: A, no es obvio de la traducción inglesa lo de la inseguridad de la mamá. Vaya, no tienes que cambiarlo.

Comment: ¿Has usado las dos acepciones de "canto" para decir que el valle estaba tanto sin voz como sin picos y redondeado? ¡Me parece una idea tan genial que solo por eso ya mereces ganar esta edición!

Comment: You, sir, are a genius!

Comment: No se que decir. aLo del canto es genial.

Comment: ¿Imagino que "capuzón" es "chapuzón"?

Comment: (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━━━━┻

Answer (score 4):

### <strike>318 283 249 240 235 212</strike> 173 caracteres

> [Eleto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EX0OaJB), [Mumin](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mumin) [esbaró](http://dle.rae.es/?id=G4d5Co8), cayó a un mundo raro, peligroso: [sumido](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YheNXpa) [inerme](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LSuw8Oa) en su primer [nevazo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QTBr7Mh), [púas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UXzFGTq) a su piel de [felpa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HjFs13g); un olor nuevo, alarmante... y [seductor](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XRdK7Je); un [val](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bHN9HUG) [albeado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1WgZuLp) en gris [umbra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=b3a2rn6), [inmóvil](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Lfaxiro), [mudo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PzhtiPx), [romo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Webfori). "Nieve -[rutó](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WrYJFY9)-, mamá lo dijo."
>
> <sub>**Carlos Alejo.**</sub>

Explicaciones:

- Tras las clarificaciones, uso "eleto" como sinónimo de "pasmado", "absorto": "con el ánimo arrebatado por alguna cosa extraordinaria".
- Si Mumin se sumió (hundirse completamente) en algo es porque cayó desde una cierta altura, y si eso es así es porque pasó más allá de un borde.
- Alguien "inerme" es que está sin armas, pero se usa también en sentido figurado, es decir, como "indefenso".
- "Nevazo", en su segunda acepción, es "nieve caída".
- "Espinas a su piel de felpa": se usa la preposición ["a"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=003Ov93) como "para" (acepción 18) o "según" (acepción 28). Equivale a "espinoso para su piel de felpa".
- No es necesario mantener la referencia al morro. Si olió algo, evidentemente fue con su morro.
- Si algo es alarmante, es que es serio.
- "Seductor" como algo que "cautiva el ánimo a alguien", es decir, como sinónimo de "interesante". Si algo es seductor o interesante es porque está despertando tu interés y atrayendo tu atención. Al dar la idea de que algo atrae tu atención ya se supone que el personaje está atento, despierto, no hay necesidad de añadir lo de *made him wide awake*.
- El valle estaba "albeado", sinónimo de "blanqueado", es decir, que se había tornado blanco, lo que indica que ese no era su color habitual (que es lo realmente importante, más que el valle antes fuera "verde").
- La palabra *twilight* se refiere a la luz tenue del amanecer o del anochecer. Dicha luz se puede traducir como "penumbra", que es la zona de sombra ubicada entre la luz y la oscuridad, o sencillamente como "umbra", zona de sombra.
- Si algo es romo, es que no tiene puntas o filos, y por tanto se puede considerar redondeado, de líneas suaves.
- En algunas zonas de españa, *rutar* significar "murmurar, susurrar". Todo el resto del texto está escrito en español de España, válido en las zonas donde se usa *rutar*.

Comment: El nevero me duele, pero comprendo que no hay tantas expresiones tratando de nieve en Español. Lo accepto. Generalmente muy buen trabajo.

Comment: Pienso que el ingles es suficientamente claro para molestarte un poco: el nevero no es el mundo nuevo sino parte de él.

Comment: @user277143 tienes razón, en cuanto pueda reordeno la frase.

Comment: @walen tanto un nevero como un snowdrift son acumulaciones de nieve, aunque la causa de la formación sea diferente. Las imágenes sí que difieren, es cierto. Puedo cambiarlo por algo más exacto con lo que me ahorro quitando "redondeado". :-)

Answer (score 4):

### <s>387 315 279 252 246 229 178</s> 173 caracteres

> Atónito, Mumin resbaló vano, ya metido en nieve incierta de un mundo *idem*. Irritó su fina piel, un nuevo olor tremendo lo avivó.
>
> Un albor gris cubría el valle cano, no verde: fijo, mudo, diluido. -Mamá lo llama nieve- musitó.

<sub>**@blonfu**</sub>

- Cambio al significado de *lost his breath* de quedar sin habla que propone Mörkö. Uso *atónito* para ello
- *Resbalar* también es caer.
- *Incierto* es algo desconocido, la nieve para Mumin en este caso.
- *Idem* se refiere a *incierta* por lo que el mundo es incierto (no seguro, peligroso y a la vez desconocido, extraño por tanto).
- *Tremendo* es algo digno de ser temido y también digno de respeto (serio, grave, importante).
- El olor lo *aviva*, por tanto esta bien despierto e interesado.

Comment: El nombre del personaje es simplemente 'Mumin' en español, puedes quitar algunas letras.

Comment: 'Lo móvil se paralizó' -> Me molesta un poco el preterito: estaba ya paralizado. Tambien 'Lo angular se redondéo' -> era ya redondeado

Comment: Dos cosas: creo que es ‘la nieve’ y ‘hirsuta’ es bastante díferente del ingles.

Comment: Tengo la palabra de dios conmigo: http://dle.rae.es/?id=QUrlLvE  : la nieve. ¿Es un fallo o tiene un sentido que no comprendo? (en la frase al fin ‘Mamá habló de ello.’)

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres decir

Comment: ¿A qué se refiere el ‘ello’?

Comment: No me refería a la nieve, sino a que hablo sobre el tema pero puedo poner también "hablo sobre ella"

Comment: No tienes que, sólo quería comprender.

Comment: El exhausto me da dudas; El dle no reconoce la palabra como 'sin aliento' sino como la palabra inglesa 'exhausted'. http://dle.rae.es/?id=HEmwiER

Comment: Sin aliento en castellano es cansado, agotado; no sé en inglés si es distinto, buscaré otra palabra si es así.

Comment: La ley de Murphy está fuerte aquí: la sóla palabra que no he verificado...

Comment: http://www.linguee.es/espanol-ingles/traduccion/quedarse+sin+aliento.html según este tiene también el mismo sentido que 'out of breath' en inglés. ¿Qué sería más claro?

Comment: ¿A lo mejor se refiere a "sorprendido"? Puede ser

Comment: Tengo un examen ahora; vamos a volver a la pregunta en algunas horas.

Comment: He decidado que porque el texto ingles, la fuente de la traducción, no es claro, voy a acceptar tres sentidos para 'He lost his breath':

1. Quedó sin palabra 2. Se cansó 3. El aire frío impedío su respiración

Answer (score 3):

## 309 caracteres

Sin aliento Moomintroll, cayó por el borde en un raro e inseguro mundo, [calándose](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20960/5481) por completo en su primera nevada, que punzaba su piel suave. Captó un olor nuevo para él. Aunque amenazador, picó su curiosidad.

El valle estaba envuelto en un ocaso gris. Todo era blanco en lugar de verde, inmóvil, silencioso y de forma redondeada. Susurró Moomintroll "Madre explicó que esto es *nieve*".

Comment: Es Moomin en español; puedes quitar dies caracteres. Te falta la parte del olor serioso. ¿Por qué? Tambien creo que falta el sentido que Mamá no estuvó segura con lo que trato de la nieve. ¿No comprendo alguna sutileza de la elección de las palabras? Por lo demás, muy bien hecho.

Comment: A, no es obvio de la traducción inglesa lo de la inseguridad de la mamá. Vaya, no tienes que cambiarlo.

Comment: Como dice Carlos Alejo, no es 'Moomin' sino 'Mumin'. Perdón.

Comment: ¿No es inmovilidad sino inmóvil? Para lo resto me parece muy bién.

Comment: @user277143 tienes razón, debería ser "inmovilidad y silencio" o "inmóvil y silencioso"