# ¿Cuál es el antónimo de "hirsuto"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, antónimos

[**Hirsuto**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KVJRa0j) es

> 1. adj. Dicho del pelo: Disperso y duro.
> 2. adj. Cubierto de pelo hirsuto o de púas o espinas.
> 3. adj. De carácter áspero.

¿Cuál sería su antónimo - si es que lo hay?

Inicialmente pensé en [**lampiño**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MrDpZ4v)

> 1. adj. Dicho de un hombre adulto: Que no tiene barba.
> 2. adj. Que tiene poco pelo o vello.

pero viendo la definición no parecen ser exactamente antónimos.

Comment: @blonfu: Tienes razón - corregido. Ya sabes eso de "Quandoque dormitat Homerus bonus" ...

Comment: Yo he pensado *lacio* que es «Flojo, débil, sin vigor.» pero refiriendose al cabello es simplemente liso, así que no encaja del todo.

Comment: @Rāhula por supuesto; ¿quén no conoce eso de "Quandoque dormitat Homerus bonus"? :-p

Comment: @SJuan76 yo lo he aprendido hoy :$

Answer (score 5):

Tanto para la primera definición como para la segunda, un posible antónimo podría ser **aterciopelado**:

> [**aterciopelado, da**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4DPZFCI)
>
> 1. adj. Semejante al [terciopelo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZXRDTdE).
> 2. adj. De finura y suavidad comparables a las del terciopelo.

Donde el pelo hirsuto es "disperso y duro", el terciopelo es velloso y tupido.
Donde lo hirsuto está cubierto de pelo disperso, duro y/o punzante, lo aterciopelado está cubierto de pelo tupido y suave.

También valdría una que se usó [en un Translation Golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22413/translation-golf-xix-moominland-midwinter):

> [**afelpado, da**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0wnTOYu)
>
> 1. adj. Parecido a la [felpa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HjFs13g%7CHjGPwoF) por tener vello o pelusilla.

Y si [buscamos en DIRAE por "pelo"](https://dirae.es/palabras/?search_type=&search_scope=&q=pelo) podemos encontrar alguna otra candidata, como por ejemplo:

> [**charraludo, da**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=charraludo)
>
> 1. adj. Nic. Dicho de una persona: Que tiene el pelo tupido, largo y enredado.

Aunque muchas son acepciones regionales poco extendidas.

Answer (score 2):

Siguiendo la misma dirección de walen, me parece que ésta palabra es bastante adecuada:

> [**sedoso, sa**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XRbJ4bG)
>
> 1. adj. Parecido a la seda o suave como ella.

De hecho, tener el *pelo sedoso* es algo que muy frecuentemente se dice en publicidad de champús (al menos en mi país).

Tengo la duda de si se puede usar con otros animales u objetos aparte del cabelllo humano, como *abrigo sedoso*, *barba sedosa* o *animal sedoso*. En estos casos me suenan mejor los ya mencionados *afelpado* y *aterciopelado*.

Answer (score 1):

Sentido 2: En México, por lo menos, se diría **pelón**.  También hay términos más universales: **calvo, glabro**.