# ¿Cómo se llama cuando *la misma* palabra cambia de significado según avanza la frase?

Tags: recurso-retórico

En las líneas de caja del Carrefour hay un cartelito:

[image]

> Agiliza tu compra y deposítala en la cinta.

En esa oración, ["**compra**"](https://dle.rae.es/?id=A2gcivD) tiene, al mismo tiempo, dos significados:

- En *"agiliza tu compra"*, "compra" se refiere a la acción de comprar.
- En *"deposíta**la** en la cinta"*, "la" se refiere a la compra... pero ya no como la acción de comprar, sino como el conjunto de los objetos comprados.

¿Tiene nombre este recurso literario, por llamarlo de alguna manera?

PD: Yo mismo he usado un recurso parecido [en alguna ocasión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22413/translation-golf-xix-moominland-midwinter#comment35808_22419), ¿es el mismo caso o es otro recurso distinto?

Comment: Yo diría que se llama "error".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probablemente esto es lo que buscas:

> **[dilogía](https://dle.rae.es/?id=DmilAOl)**
>
> Del lat. *dilogĭa*, y este del gr. διλογία *dilogía*.
>
> **1.** f. Empleo de una palabra que hay que entender en dos sentidos distintos a la vez dentro del mismo enunciado, como en *salió de la cárcel con tanta honra, que le acompañaron doscientos* cardenales, *sino que a ninguno llamaban "señoría"*.

En este caso el DRAE ejemplifica con un quevedismo bien conocido, en el que se juega con los dos significados de la palabra *cardenales* ("prelados" y "hematomas"), del mismo modo que en la frase de la pregunta se juega con distintos significados de la palabra *compra*.

Este recurso también se conoce como *antanaclasis*, *diáfora*, y más generalmente como *equívoco*.

Sin embargo, concediendo por completo la razón a @Gustavson, me parece que un concepto tan bonito y tan griego como éste debería aplicarse a casos intencionales, que pretendan generar un efecto llamativo, novedoso o inteligente, y no a los que ocurren por puro descuido.

Comment: No veo lo de los "sentidos distintos" en el caso de "compra", 1. f. Acción y efecto de comprar. 2. f. Conjunto de los comestibles que se compran para el gasto diario de las casas. U. solo en sing. 3. f. Objeto comprado.

Answer (score 2):

Personalmente, considero que la redacción de la frase es defectuosa, pues el pronombre enclítico "la" no encuentra su referente en la palabra "compra" según su acepción inicial (el acto de comprar) sino en una segunda acepción (el producto de la compra).

Esta variación es posible gracias a la polisemia de la palabra "compra", existiendo entre las dos acepciones una relación metonímica, posiblemente entre una causa abstracta y su efecto concreto ( https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonimia ).

Un ejemplo similar, aunque no tan crítico, sería:

- Gestionó un préstamo y lo usó (el dinero obtenido a través del préstamo) para comprar un automóvil.

Aunque a expensas de la economía del texto, corregiría el texto en cuestión así:

- Agiliza tu compra y deposita los productos (comprados) ...

En conclusión:

- No considero que se trate de un "recurso literario".
- Considero que simplemente se trata de un mal uso de la lengua.

Comment: @Potter-Pirbright Lo agregué como conclusión.

Comment: Encuentro más acertada la respuesta de @Gustavson que la de Rodrigo por la misma razón que Rodrigo le da la razón a Gustavson por un lado, uno es intencional el otro no, y por otro lado el pronombre anafórico, como bien dice Gustavson, hace una falsa referencia.

Comment: Tan simple como mirar la definición. "Préstamo" es tanto la acción y efecto de prestar como la cantidad prestada. "Compra" es tanto la acción y efecto de comprar como los productos comprados. "Siembra" es tanto la acción y efecto de sembrar como el terreno sembrado.

Comment: @roetnig El punto es que no es un buen uso de la lengua mezclar distintas acepciones de una palabra en una misma oración.

Comment: "Realiza la suma y escríbela a continuación" Suma, acción y efecto de sumar, resultado de la suma. No se donde ves la incorrección.

Comment: @roetnig "...y escribe el resultado a continuación."

Answer (score 2):

## [**Anacoluto**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=2UDI8MV)

> Inconsecuencia en la construcción del discurso.

Por incapacidad o precipitación del redactor de este cartel, la oración tiene una forma inconsecuente en su redacción final.

1. Tal como apunta el *OP*, se quiere hablar al principio de la frase de la **acción** de comprar y, a mitad de ella, se utiliza el concepto (a través del "la") con un significado distinto, aunque relacionado. Ni se puede colocar una acción en la cinta, ni agilizar un objeto.
2. La conjunción "y" parece unir dos acciones del mismo orden (consecutivas *temporalmente*), cuando en realidad se precisaría una relación (subordinada) causal. Es decir: *acción primera (**debido a**) acción segunda*. De esta manera, el comprador entiende que la causa de la agilización es la colocación en la cinta.
   A veces, "y" tiene un valor *consecutivo* pero habría que haber invertido el orden de las acciones: "Deposita tu compra en la cinta y (así, como consecuencia) agilízala". Pero el problema primero aún persistiría.

No es un recurso retórico, sino una forma errónea de expresarse.